# WebComponent with shadowDOM and without

Tags: javascript, html, css, components

I have this code and I want to use a CSS framework, like UIKit. In the index.html, where the component will be used I inserted the UIKit cdn. How I can use the class "**uk-text-bold**" on the **p** tag and take the style from the framework inside the *parent*?

```
class liveSearchComenziClienti extends HTMLElement {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

    const html = `
        <style>
            .foo {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>

        <p class="foo">test</p>
    `;

    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = html;
}

    connectedCallback() {

    }
}
```

customElements.define('live-search-comenzi-clienti', liveSearchComenziClienti);

Answer (score 0):

Given that the whole point of a shadowdom is to ISOLATE script from the parent dom, then it can’t use the parent's resources just as the parent can’t use those of the shadowdom.

The bottom line is that you’ll have to treat them as two separate doms by adding the 3rd party resource file again just as you would in the parent...

```
const html ='

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="somelib.css">

        <style>
            .foo {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
    
        <p class="foo">test</p>
    ';

    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = html;
}
```

**Sidenote:**

Up until a few months ago all these websites were using shadowdoms but most seem to have abandoned them now... not sure why but I'm very curious to know.

The reason I've got this list is because I was working on a utility that interrogates shadowdoms etc, and I went through hundreds of websites before I could find this bunch.

```
www.theguardian.com
www.standard.co.uk
www.reddit.com
www.irishtimes.com
www.abc.net.au/news
www.news.com.au
part-theme.glitch.me
www.mirror.co.uk
www.youtube.com
```

Comment: Ok. I understand what you say. And if I have, let's say, 10 separate components (classes) (which are not related to each other), does that mean that in each of them I have to add the library (if I use shadowDOM)?
Won't that make the page more difficult to load?